# Storm HDFS Bolt not working

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-storm, hortonworks-data-platform

So I've just started working with storm and trying to understand it. I am trying to connect to the kafka topic, read the data and write it to the HDFS bolt.
At first I created it without the shuffleGrouping("stormspout") and my Storm UI was showing that the spout was consuming the data from the topic but nothing was being written to the bolt (except for the empty files it was creating on the HDFS) . I then added shuffleGrouping("stormspout"); and now the bolt appears to be giving an error. If anyone can help with this, I will really appreciate it.

Thanks,
Colman

**Error**

> 2015-04-13 00:02:58 s.k.PartitionManager [INFO] Read partition information from: /storm/partition_0  --> null
>      2015-04-13 00:02:58 s.k.PartitionManager [INFO] No partition information found, using configuration to determine offset
>      2015-04-13 00:02:58 s.k.PartitionManager [INFO] Last commit offset from zookeeper: 0
>      2015-04-13 00:02:58 s.k.PartitionManager [INFO] Commit offset 0 is more than 9223372036854775807 behind, resetting to startOffsetTime=-2
>      2015-04-13 00:02:58 s.k.PartitionManager [INFO] Starting Kafka 192.168.134.137:0 from offset 0
>      2015-04-13 00:02:58 s.k.ZkCoordinator [INFO] Task [1/1] Finished refreshing
>      2015-04-13 00:02:58 b.s.d.task [INFO] Emitting: stormspout default [colmanblah]
>      2015-04-13 00:02:58 b.s.d.executor [INFO] TRANSFERING tuple TASK: 2 TUPLE: source: stormspout:3, stream: default, id: {462820364856350458=5573117062061876630}, [colmanblah]
>      2015-04-13 00:02:58 b.s.d.task [INFO] Emitting: stormspout __ack_init [462820364856350458 5573117062061876630 3]
>       2015-04-13 00:02:58 b.s.d.executor [INFO] TRANSFERING tuple TASK: 1 TUPLE: source: stormspout:3, stream: __ack_init, id: {}, [462820364856350458 5573117062061876630 3]
>       2015-04-13 00:02:58 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message FOR 1 TUPLE: source: stormspout:3, stream: __ack_init, id: {}, [462820364856350458 5573117062061876630 3]
>      2015-04-13 00:02:58 b.s.d.executor [INFO] BOLT ack TASK: 1 TIME:  TUPLE: source: stormspout:3, stream: __ack_init, id: {}, [462820364856350458 5573117062061876630 3]
>      2015-04-13 00:02:58 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Execute done TUPLE source: stormspout:3, stream: __ack_init, id: {}, [462820364856350458 5573117062061876630 3] TASK: 1 DELTA:
>      2015-04-13 00:02:59 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Prepared bolt stormbolt:(2)
>      2015-04-13 00:02:59 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Processing received message FOR 2 TUPLE: source: stormspout:3, stream: default, id: {462820364856350458=5573117062061876630}, [colmanblah]

2015-04-13 00:02:59 b.s.util [ERROR] Async loop died!

```
            java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
                    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:128) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:99) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5697$fn__5710$fn__5761.invoke(executor.clj:794) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__452.invoke(util.clj:465) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_71]
            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
                    at org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.HdfsBolt.execute(HdfsBolt.java:92) ~[storm-hdfs-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5697$tuple_action_fn__5699.invoke(executor.clj:659) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__5620.invoke(executor.clj:415) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__1741.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:120) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    ... 6 common frames omitted
            2015-04-08 04:26:39 b.s.d.executor [ERROR]
            java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
                    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:128) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:99) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5697$fn__5710$fn__5761.invoke(executor.clj:794) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__452.invoke(util.clj:465) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_71]
            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
                    at org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.HdfsBolt.execute(HdfsBolt.java:92) ~[storm-hdfs-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5697$tuple_action_fn__5699.invoke(executor.clj:659) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__5620.invoke(executor.clj:415) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__1741.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
                    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:120) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041.jar:0.9.3.2.2.0.0-2041]
```

**Code:**

```
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();    
    Config config = new Config();
    //config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TRIDENT_BATCH_EMIT_INTERVAL_MILLIS, 7000);
    config.setNumWorkers(1);
    config.setDebug(true);  
    //LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();


    //zookeeper
    BrokerHosts brokerHosts = new ZkHosts("192.168.134.137:2181", "/brokers");      

    //spout
    SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(brokerHosts, "myTopic", "/kafkastorm", "KafkaSpout");
    spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
    spoutConfig.forceFromStart = true;
    builder.setSpout("stormspout", new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig),4);

    //bolt
    SyncPolicy syncPolicy = new CountSyncPolicy(10); //Synchronize data buffer with the filesystem every 10 tuples
    FileRotationPolicy rotationPolicy = new FileSizeRotationPolicy(5.0f, Units.MB); // Rotate data files when they reach five MB
    FileNameFormat fileNameFormat = new DefaultFileNameFormat().withPath("/stormstuff"); // Use default, Storm-generated file names
    builder.setBolt("stormbolt", new HdfsBolt()
                                 .withFsUrl("hdfs://192.168.134.137:8020")//54310
                                 .withSyncPolicy(syncPolicy)
                                 .withRotationPolicy(rotationPolicy)
                                 .withFileNameFormat(fileNameFormat),2
                    ).shuffleGrouping("stormspout");        


    //cluster.submitTopology("ColmansStormTopology", config, builder.createTopology());     

    try {
        StormSubmitter.submitTopologyWithProgressBar("ColmansStormTopology", config, builder.createTopology());

    } catch (AlreadyAliveException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidTopologyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**POM.XML dependencies**

```
              <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
                <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
                <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency> 
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
                <artifactId>storm-hdfs</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.3</version>
            </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
                        <version>0.8.1.1</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
              </dependencies>
```

Comment: Before you add the `shuffleGrouping` to spout & bolt wasn't connected.
Once you connect the bolt actually start processing data. you will need to share your bolt & spout code and add some traces to bolt

Comment: Yeah I thought that was what was happening, that is all my code? Should I have something else? Again I've just started looking at storm, I've been using flume up until now. Cheers, Colman

Comment: You can run storm in a local mode so you can debug it with your IDE

Comment: Yeah... I cant really do that as I'm developing on windows at the moment and running the app on a hortonworks sandbox while we are waiting for our cluster to arrive....

Comment: ok , clearly this is error in the bolt, if you can't run it in local mode, add traces in your code and see where it fail, if you want someone here to help, share your code with us

Comment: That is all my code! Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: where is the `HdfsBolt` ? or it's part of the frame work ?

Comment: Its a part of the framework:  org.apache.storm.hdfs.bolt.HdfsBolt.HdfsBolt()

Comment: link to the bolt code here: https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/external/storm-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/hdfs/bolt/HdfsBolt.java

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to emit the values from the execute method, if you are emitting from different worker thread, then let all the worker threads to feed the data in LinkedBlockingQueue and only a single worker thread will allow to emit the values from LinkedBlockingQueue.

Secondly, try to Set Config.setMaxSpoutPending to some value and again try to run the code, and check if the scenario persist try to reduce that value.

Reference - Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING: This sets the maximum number of spout tuples that can be pending on a single spout task at once (pending means the tuple has not been acked or failed yet). It is highly recommended you set this config to prevent queue explosion.

Comment: I set the max_spout_pending and that hasn't made a difference, I don't emit anything as thats all done within the framework. Are you talking about overiding the KafkaSpout execute method? I really feel like this is a version mismatch somehow. Maybe some jar file is pulling in an incorrect dependency or perhaps my pom,xml is wrong? I've added in the pom file dependencies above if you could take a look?

Comment: I've included the error block before the error, Can anyone help with this?!

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured this out by going through the storm source code.

I wasn't setting

```
RecordFormat format = new DelimitedRecordFormat().withFieldDelimiter("|");
```

and including it like

```
    builder.setBolt("stormbolt", new HdfsBolt()
                                      .withFsUrl("hdfs://192.168.134.137:8020")//54310
                                 .withSyncPolicy(syncPolicy)
                                 .withRecordFormat(format)
                                 .withRotationPolicy(rotationPolicy)
                                 .withFileNameFormat(fileNameFormat),1
                    ).shuffleGrouping("stormspout");
```

In the HDFSBolt.Java class, it tries to use this and basically falls over if its not set. That was where the NPE was coming from.

Hope this helps someone else out, ensure you have set all the bits that are required in this class. A more useful error message such as "RecordFormat not set" would be nice....